A mathematical problem to find the length of a line segment
Consider the following picture, an equilateral triangle ABC:

What I want to find is, the length of the line segment EH as a function of $\theta$, which is the angle between the line EH and EF. EF is parallel to the base BC of the triangle and has a known length. Here, is what approach I have taken.
I have further drawn two lines. One from F to H at G and G to I. It is seen that FG $\bot$ GI.
First of all, consider all the known values to be given a name. Here, $EG=a$, $FG=b$ and $GI=c$
Now,
$$
EH^2=EF^2+FH^2-2.EF.FH.cos(-120^\circ)=x^2+d^2+xd
$$
where $x$ is the length of the unknown segment FH and $d$ is the length of the known segment EF. Furthermore, in right-angled triangle FGI, applying Pythagoras, we can reach to:
$$
FI^2=FG^2+GI^2=b^2+c^2
$$
where $b=d\tan\theta$ and $c=d\sqrt3\tan\theta$ [by applying trigonometric ratio twice, $b=d\tan30^\circ$ and then putting the value of $b$]. Moreover, the side FH can be written as:
$$
FH=FI+IH
$$
but FI is known which is:
$$
FI=\sqrt{FG^2+GI^2}=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}
$$
Furthermore, for triangle GIH, we can apply the same theorem to arrive at:
$$
GH^2=GI^2+IH^2+GI.IH
$$
Here, IH appears to be new. Substituting it with previous two unknowns, we can establish the relation:
$$
IH=FH-FI\Rightarrow IH^2=(FH-FI)^2=x^2+b^2+c^2-2x\sqrt{b^2+c^2}
$$
Putting value of $b$ and $c$, IH reduces to:
$$
IH^2=(x-2d\tan\theta)^2
$$
It gives us GH:
$$
GH^2=c^2+(x-2d\tan\theta)^2+c(x-2d\tan\theta)
$$
$$
GH^2=x^2-4xd\tan\theta+7d^2\tan^2\theta+cx-2cd\tan\theta
$$
$$
GH^2=x^2+mx+k^2
$$
where, it has been considered that $m=c-4d\tan\theta$ and $k=7d^2\tan^2\theta-2cd\tan
\theta$
Now, breaking down EH as $EH=EG+GH$. we get:
$$
x^2+d^2+xd=(a+GH)^2
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x^2+d^2+xd=a^2+GH^2+2a\cdot GH
$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+d^2+xd=a^2+x^2+mx+k^2+2a\sqrt{x^2+mx+k^2}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow [(d^2-a^2-k^2)+x(d-m)]^2=4a^2(x^2+mx+k^2)
$$
Considering this whole constant part $d^2-a^2-k^2$to be z, which reduces the rigorousness of our equation, we arrive at:
$$
\Rightarrow z^2+x^2(d-m)^2+2zx(d-m)=4a^2x^2+4a^2mx+4a^2k^2
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x^2[(d-m)^2-4a^2]+x[2z(d-m)-4a^2m]+z^2-4a^2k^2=0
$$
Solving this equation gives two values of $x$. Putting this value in the equation of EH, I can find EH.
My question is, is this approach correct? Why are there two values of x, instead of one?

To be clear: $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, correct?

I think you need to know the measure of angle $A$.

Have you considered using the Law of Sines in $\triangle EFH$?

"Why are there two values of x, instead of one?" When you square both sides of an equation you usually add an extraneous value.  You need to keep the one where what is being squared are compatible signs. I.e. the one where $x^2 + mx + k^2$ and $(d^2-a^2-k^2)+x(d-m)$ are both non-negative.

@Blue yes it is

@Blue that's an excellent solution, why did not it appear to my mind before. Many many thanks. It worked.

You really should include the triangle is equilateral.  In general this will require knowing the measure of $\angle EFH$.  That there is a base, that it is parallel to $EF$ what any of the angles of the triangle, or even that there is a triangle are irrelevant.
